# Use another function in a function does not work with multiprocess.Pool

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, multiprocess

I tried to use another function inside a function, and use `Pool` to `map` it to multi-core. And it failed. How to use multi-level function in `Pool`? python 3.6.4

```
from multiprocess import Pool


def fun(x):
    return fun1(x)

def fun1(x):
    return x**2

pool = Pool(4)

pool.map(fun,[1,2,3,4])
```

Output:

> NameError: name 'fun1' is not defined

Comment: `>>> pool.map(fun,[1,2,3,4])
[1, 4, 9, 16]
` Cannot reproduce on linux. Are you on windows? In this case you have to put the code following `def fun1` into the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block at the end of the file.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue (python 2.7.15 and 3.6.6). Please post a proper MCVE.

Comment: I am on Windows 10. Maybe it's because of my company's anti-virus software. I am going to test it on other machine and go back.

Comment: I'm the `multiprocess` author. I have tested your code exactly as above with python3.6, with the current development version of `multiprocess`, and on a mac.  It produces `[1, 4, 9, 16]`, as expected.  If you are on windows, it should also work... but it's suggested that you use a '`if __name__ == '__main__'` block that also uses `freeze_support`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code is working fine at my end. the only thing I changed is the entry point for the program check below code:

```
from multiprocess import Pool
def fun(x):
    print fun1(x)

def fun1(x):
    return x**2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(4)
    pool.map(fun,[1,2,3,4])
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. Let my check my environment first.